# emulator windows azure compute emulator does not work, and the following error appears:

Tags: sql-server, azure

emulator windows azure compute emulator does not work, and the following error appears:

windows azure tool for microsoft visual studio

The system is missing a prerequisite to run the service. see output windows for more information

already installed the sdk for visual studio 2012 and I believe the azure tool already come with this but still can not run the emulator. Thank someone help al.

Comment: You can look this answer via below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34328711/2123797

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 main components which are installed with Windows Azure SDK when you do full install on 32 or 64 bit machines and those components are:

1. Windows Azure Tools
2. Windows Azure Libraries
3. Windows Azure Authoring Tools
4. Windows Azure Emulator

You first step towards investigation would be to check your installation and verify that you do have all above components installed. In case you have all 4 components installed and still get the exact same error, go ahead and uninstall everything related to windows Azure first. And as you are using VS2012, you can install full WebPI version of latest Windows Azure SDK for  VS2012 from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254364&clcid=0x409).